# How to clear data on database after each run?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

How can I clear all the data on my database after each run  or in other words, start a new database whenever I run my application ?

Comment: The word "run" in the sense of a sessions of execution doesn't really apply to android in the way it does to programs in more usual contexts.  You are going to have to do some thinking about where in the activity lifecycle it is appropriate to do such clearing.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this code, In the Finally part it is clearing the database. Likewise you need to implement your logic.

```
package com.collabera.labs.sai.db;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class CRUDonDB extends ListActivity {

    private final String SAMPLE_DB_NAME = "myFriendsDb";
    private final String SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME = "friends";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;

        try {
            sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

            sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " (LastName VARCHAR, FirstName VARCHAR," +
                    " Country VARCHAR, Age INT(3));");

            sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " Values ('Makam','Sai Geetha','India',25);");
            sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " Values ('Chittur','Raman','India',25);");
            sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " Values ('Solutions','Collabera','India',20);");

            Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT FirstName, Age FROM " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " where Age > 10 LIMIT 5", null);

            if (c != null ) {
                if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName"));
                        int age = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Age"));
                        results.add("" + firstName + ",Age: " + age);
                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                } 
            }

            this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));

        } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
        } finally {
            if (sampleDB != null) 
                sampleDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME);
                sampleDB.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete all rows from the table on every run and insert new dataq when ever required.

Follow the below method to delete all data from a table.

```
void deleteAllData()
{
    SQLiteDatabase sdb= this.getWritableDatabase();
    sdb.delete(tablename, null, null);

}
```